# How to Initialize third party JavaScript asynchronous library before loading AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, birt

I'm facing problem while initializing a third party JavaScript API (iHUB) inside RUN method of AngularJS. Currently the code is behaving in asynchronous mode. I want IHUB to first initialize and then AngularJS route/controller should get called. (Is it possible to make utilization of the callback method provided by IHUB ?)

```
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', ['ngRoute']);

nameApp.run(['$window', 'myService', function($window, myService) {

   //initialize IHUB
   var actuate= new actuate();
   actuate.initialize('http://localhost:8700/iportal', settings.reqOps, "user", "pwd", callback);

   function callback(){
     alert('started!!');
   }

}]);

nameApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/:tabname', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/analyticsDetail.html',
      controller: 'tabDetailCtrl'
    }).
    when('/:tabname/:reportName', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/analyticsDetail.html',
      controller: 'reportDetailCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/Buy Side Dashboard'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Use route resolvers for that.

Comment: `angular.config` runs first and configures the app before it even bootstraps (starts), `angular.run` will run when injector is created and therefore after other methods so it can use event listeners. [More about it](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Angular-Module-Loading/). Since config is for providers, try to initialise inside it (`resolve` / `$provide`)

Comment: have you tried to just include the file first on your html declaration of angular.js?

Comment: Any feedback Manu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way to achieve a "real" before AngularJS initialization behavior by using [angular.bootstrap();](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap). This allows you to initialize your AngularJS application manually.

> **Note:** You should not use the ng-app directive when manually bootstrapping your app.

**> [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/os55fp7n/1/)**

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  Hello, {{greetMe}}!
</div>
```

#### Application

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greetMe = 'World';
  }]);

var actuateDummy = {
  initialize: function (callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 2500);
  }
};

actuateDummy.initialize(function () {
  angular.element(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });
})
```

---

### This is an other approach which uses the `resolve` state of `ui-router`. This service only initializes `iHUB` if it not has been initialized yet:

This service also returns the `actuate` object. In that way you can use it in your controller or components after init.

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z420thsj/)**

#### View

```
<nav>
  <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
  <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("state1", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 1</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl1",
    resolve: {
      iHubInit: function(iHubService) {
        return iHubService.init()
      }
    }
  }).state("state2", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 2</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl2",
    resolve: {
      iHubInit: function(iHubService) {
        return iHubService.init()
      }
    }
  });
});

myApp.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, iHubService) {
  console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

myApp.controller("Ctrl2", function($scope, iHubService) {
  console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});

myApp.service('iHubService', ["$q", function($q) {

  this.iHubServiceInitialized = false;
  this.actuate = null;

  this.init = function() {

    if (!this.iHubServiceInitialized) {

      //Init
      var self = this;
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      this.actuate = new actuate();

      //initialize
      this.actuate.initialize('http://localhost:8700/iportal', settings.reqOps, "user", "pwd", function() {
        self.iHubServiceInitialized = true;
        deferred.resolve(self.actuate);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    } else {
      return this.actuate;
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: your 1st solution is working fine. but, using route resolver, the initialization is getting called multiple times. I think problem with **iHubServiceInitialized ** variable which is resetting to false every time service called.

Comment: @Manu, nope. `iHubServiceInitialized` is not resetted -> you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/654qesvv/. A service is a single object which is injected with the same state into every component where you want to use it.

Comment: corrected the service code. Now its working fine. thanks once again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a resolve attribute when configuring your route provider like below:

```
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', ['ngRoute']);

nameApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/:tabname', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/analyticsDetail.html',
      controller: 'tabDetailCtrl',
      resolve: {
                ihubInit: ['iHubService', function (iHubService) {
                    return iHubService.init();
                }]
            }
    }).
    when('/:tabname/:reportName', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/analyticsDetail.html',
      controller: 'reportDetailCtrl',
      resolve: {
                ihubInit: ['iHubService', function (iHubService) {
                    return iHubService.init();
                }]
            }
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/Buy Side Dashboard'
    });
}]);

nameApp.service('iHubService', ["$q", function($q){
  this.init = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var actuate= new actuate();
    actuate.initialize('http://localhost:8700/iportal', settings.reqOps, "user", "pwd", callback);

    function callback(){
       deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But, IHUB initialize should be called only once (This is like a login to iHub server) .  With route provider, it is initializing ihub every time route parameter change.

Comment: Well just add a boolean `initialized` and set it to true when iHub is initialized and don't call again if this boolean is true. But @lin answer is probably the good one ;-)